# Eclipse Juno no JSP in Dynamic Web Project (but everything else is fine)

Tags: eclipse, jsp

The short question, is when creating dynamic web project (1.6 jdk) I can see all file types to create but there is no option for jsp. To add to that when I check file associations there is no JSP editor to select from.

A slightly longer version is I simply want to edit JSP files, I have Juno EE version installed and it says web tools platform is installed and everything works just fine.

However while everything works, there was no *.jsp in file associations and on adding it there was no JSP editor in the list. This is an out of the box Juno EE.

So I checked installed plugins and it tells me that web tools is installed, there is an icon and a load of plugins. They are all listed under Java EE in the plugin/installation list. I even tried installing just 'java web develop tools' which lists as 'tools for working with jsp' but when I do that I get ""Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools" will be ignored because it is already installed." however I cannot uninstall it because it's part of Java EE eclipse platform. I have no other plugins installed that might have broken this, however it has taken some time to get all the settings good so I'd rather not install it all again.

So I tried to install the full WTP by hand and it said some things were already installed, but it installed others. However, still no JSP editor. Hence why I tried a dynamic web project to see if I could create JSP and it wasn't listed.

So, eclipse base install has absolutely everything (xml, html editor, java editor, all the tools) but just not JSP.

My JDK is fine as dynamic web project is not created unless you have a valid 1.6 or above.

Anyone help?

Comment: Which 1.6 JDK is it?  Have you added anything to its ext folder?  What platform are you on?  Is there anything else missing?  Have you checked the .log file for messages?  Is there anything installed in addition to what was in the Java EE package?

Comment: @Neil have you already solved this problem? I encountered the same issue as yours.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue but with kepler version. I have spring tools plugin installed apart from the base Java EE. If you have fixed the issue, could you please share the steps.

Answer (score 5):

It seems your missing Eclipse web developer tools and Eclipse java web developer tools.

Help>Install new software>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno, select appropriate items under Web,XML,Java EE

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse Juno, select File/New/Other, then type in jsp in the wizard field. Select jsp file or jsp tag and there you go. Hope that helps.

Comment: It's not there. No jsp editor, no file association. Nothing. Hence my longer explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to install Eclipse with Java EE developer.It should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to Eclipse Market place and search for "Java EE Developer tool". On clicking it you should be able to see if your Web developer tool is selected or not. Please select that option and your issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Check your path.  Make sure it is pointing to at least a 1.6 version of Java.  Restart Eclipse.  That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed every thing proper and still it is not showing JSP option while creating new .jsp file then click to the web icon on top right corner of eclipse. If it doesn't work then you need to install updated version of eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem; I looked through the "Web,XML,Java EE..." installables available at under Kepler downloads:[image]

and that brought me the New->'JSP File' context menu item.